# How do I stop python from computing (-2)^0.5 into a complex number, and give me an exception instead

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am taking a beginners course in python at my uni and I have am preparing a test on exceptions tomorrow. 
I am trying to work out the geometric mean from a list. When I enter a negative value into the list, python calculates the geometric mean and gives me a complex number (obviously). 
However in prep for my test I want an exception to be raised when there's a negative value in the list, but I don't know how to do this? would anybody help.

I am working in python3.4. if you want to see my code here. any other advice on how to make my code more efficient let me know. thanks in advance.

```
            #LOAD A LIST 
            while True:
                try:
                    string = input("please enter a list of numbers separated by commas \n:",)
                    L = [float(x) for x in string.split(",")]
                    #print(L)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("There seems to be a value error in that list")
                    pass

            #COMPUTE GEOMETRIC MEAN
            def gm(L):
                cnt = 1
                try:
                    for i in range(len(L)):
                        cnt=cnt*L[i]
                    geo = (cnt)**(1/len(L))
                    return geo
                except ValueError:
                    print("Value error!")
                except TypeError:
                    print("type error!")

            print("geometric mean is, ", gm(L))
```

Answer (score 3):

First method, test and raise exceptions yourself.

Second method, use `math.pow` instead of builtin operator.

Comment: Re: Second method: `math.pow()` will raise a `ValueError: math domain error` exception, which is fine, but it would simpler to just use the built-in `pow()` function as it raises a `ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power` — which is arguably more explicit and therefore probably easier for most folks to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Python cannot be configured to change such fundamental behaviours, but you can raise your own exceptions whenever you want.

```
def gm(L):
    if any(x < 0 for x in L):
        raise ValueError("List cannot have negative values")
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly raise an exception if the product is negative, e.g.:

```
if cnt < 0:
   raise ValueError('Negative product')
geo = (cnt)**(1/len(L))
return geo
```

Here's a tutorial on [raising exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions).